# How to create class based views in Django with nested crud?

Tags: django

I was able to refactor half of my code to Class Based Views, but I am having a hard time with the nested crud portion of it. Here are my code. I am trying to refactor all the reviews to Class Views. I am new to this. Any advice would be helpful.
Thank you.

I have two models here. One is for Beer and the other is Review. A beer has many reviews so when I go to Beer_List, I am able to access all the reviews for that beer. I just don't know how to refactor the review into class based views.

```
from .models import Beer, Review 
from .forms import BeerForm, ReviewForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect



def get_beer(beer_id): 
    return Beer.objects.get(id=beer_id)

def beer_list(request): 
    beers = Beer.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'beers/beer_list.html', {'beers': beers})

def new_beer(request): 
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = BeerForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            beer = form.save(commit=False)
            beer.save()
            return redirect('beer_detail', beer_id=beer.id)    
    else: 
        form = BeerForm()      
    return render(request, 'beers/beer_form.html', {'form': form, "type_of_reqeust": "New"})

def beer_detail(request, beer_id): 
    beer = get_beer(beer_id)
    return render (request, 'beers/beer_detail.html',  {'beer': beer})

def edit_beer(request, beer_id): 
    beer = get_beer(beer_id)
    form = BeerForm(request.POST or None, instance=beer)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('beer_list')   
    return render(request, 'beers/beer_form.html', {'form': form, 'type_of_reqeust': 'Edit'})


def delete_beer(request, beer_id): 
    if request.method =="POST": 
        beer = get_beer(beer_id)
        beer.delete()
    return redirect('beer_list') 






def get_review(review_id): 
    return Review.objects.get(id=review_id)


def review_list(request, beer_id):
    beer = get_beer(beer_id)
    reviews =  beer.reviews.all()
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_list.html', {'beer' : beer, 'reviews': reviews})


def new_review(request, beer_id): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.beer = get_beer(beer_id)
            review.save()
            return redirect('review_detail',  beer_id=review.beer.id, review_id=review.id)
    else: 
        form = ReviewForm()
    return render (request, 'reviews/review_form.html', {'form' : form, 'type_of_request': 'New'})


def review_detail(request, beer_id, review_id): 
    beer = get_beer(beer_id)
    review = get_review(review_id)
    return render (request, 'reviews/review_detail.html', {'beer': beer, 'review': review})


def edit_review(request, beer_id, review_id): 
    beer = get_beer(beer_id)
    review = get_review(review_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None, instance=review)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        review = form.save(commit=False)
        review.save()
        return redirect('review_detail', review_id=review.id, beer_id=beer.id)
    return render (request, 'reviews/review_form.html', {'form' : form, 'type_of_request': 'Edit'})


def delete_review(request, beer_id, review_id):
    if request.method=="POST": 
        review = get_review(review_id)
        review.delete()
    return redirect('beer_list')
```

This is what I currently have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import * 

# Create your views here.

class BeerList(ListView): 
    model = Beer
    template_name = 'beers/beer_list.html'

class BeerDetail(DetailView):
    model = Beer
    template_name = 'beers/beer_detail.html'


class BeerCreate(CreateView): 
    model = Beer
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'beers/beer_form.html'
    success_url = '/beers/'

class BeerUpdate(UpdateView): 
    model = Beer
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'beers/beer_form.html'
    success_url = '/beers/'

class BeerDelete(DeleteView): 
    model = Beer
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ratings:beer_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have two models

```
class Beer(models.Model):
class Review(models.Model):
```

If there is a foreign key relationship in `Review` like:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    # ...
    beer = models.ForeignKey(Beer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in your templates, Django provides a helper for "Related objects reference" thats used like `<relation>_set.all`.
Here I assume `beer` has a `name` and `review` has a `body`

```html
<!-- beer_detail.html -->
<h1>{{beer.name}}</h1>
<h1>Reviews</h1>
{% for review in beer.review_set.all %}
    <p>{{review.body}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```